# how to find color name based on color code?

Tags: android, android-resources, color-codes

I have color code #ffa100. I have also define it in values xml as

```
 <color name="orange">#ffa100</color>
```

I want to find name "orange" based on the color code value "#ffa100" How can I find it? I want to use name of color in program from value where several colors are defined and I get has code from server.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it directly from with the hex code, no need to have it in resources. Hex value has to be a String.

`your_image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa100"))`

Comment: I want to search color name "orange" which is defined in XML, using code #ffa100 how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
Color.parseColor("#ffa100");
```

like,

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa100")); //set text color
mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa100")); // set background color
```